# How can I upload a presentation that I made in Microsoft Word Notebook Layout (that includes images, video and text) to YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I'm trying to upload a Microsoft Word Notebook Layout document (that includes images, video and text) to YouTube.

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be on Youtube? Can it be an online powerpoint instead?

Comment: a) MS Word isn't the right tool for making slide deck. b) Slide decks aren't videos - you must record your presentation as video first and then try to upload it to YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that cannot be done.

The hand-wavy answer to your question would be that for YouTube to extract the video, or somehow interpret a Word document as a video, is out of scope for their service. Basically, you'll have to upload a ready-made video file.

The official answer to your question is that [per the online help for YouTube](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55744), the supported file formats are: [WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM), [MPEG4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4), [3GPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GPP), [MOV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.mov), [AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave), [MPEGPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_program_stream), [WMV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video), [FLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video).

You have two choices:

1. Find some software, or other means, to convert your Word file into one of the above mentioned supported video formats
2. Re-create the content as a video

My tip would be to get your content into PowerPoint, and use a software package to convert your PowerPoint file into a video file. There are existing converters out there, as well as screen recorders that would help with this part.